# How do I force a Primefaces calendar to update after a change Ajax event validates the new value?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, ajax-update

I'm modifying a page with two Calendar components, to select a start date and an end date. I'm supposed to make them check that the start date is before the end date whenever you modify either of them; if the start is set after the end or viceversa, the code changes the end date to the maximum date and pops a warning.

The event listeners run correctly, but the end date calendar fails to update to reflect the new value; it's not that it updates before the listener changes the value ─it fails to update at all.

The project runs on Primefaces 5.3 and Java 1.6. This is the xhtml (minus styles for readability):

```
<p:outputPanel id="fl83">
    <p:outputPanel id="fl83c3">
        <h:outputLabel value="Start date" for="fechaInicioMP" />
        <p:calendar locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="fechaInicioMP"
            maxdate="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaMaxFin}" value="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaInicio}"
            onSelectUpdate=":f183" >
            <p:ajax event="blur" />
            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaInicioTextChange}"
                render="@this" update="@form" />
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaInicioClickChange}"
                update="@form" />
        </p:calendar>
    </p:outputPanel>
    <p:outputPanel id="fl83c4">
        <h:outputLabel value="End date" for="fechaFinMP" />
        <p:calendar locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="fechaFinMP"
            maxdate="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaMaxFin}" value="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaFin}"
            onSelectUpdate=":f183" >
            <p:ajax event="blur" />
            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaFinTextChange}"
                render="@this" update=":fl83" />
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaFinClickChange}"
                update=":fl83" />
        </p:calendar>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

And these are the listeners:

```
    public void fechaFinTextChange() {
    if(fechaFin.after(fechaMaxFin)) {
        fechaFin = fechaMaxFin;
        addErrorMessage(FFIN_AFTER_FMAX);
    }
    compareInicioBeforeFin();
}

public void fechaFinClickChange(SelectEvent event) {
    setFechaFin((Date)event.getObject()); // I couldn't find out why this is here given that
                                          // the setter has already been called
    compareInicioBeforeFin();
    if (updateMetodoEntreBB != null) {
        ajaxActualiza(event, OpcionesAjax.F_FIN);
    }
}

// fechaInicioTextChange and fechaInicioClickChange do pretty much the same as these two

private void compareInicioBeforeFin() {
    if(fechaInicio.after(fechaFin)) {
        fechaFin = fechaMaxFin;
        addErrorMessage(FINI_AFTER_FFIN);
    }
}
```

There are two Ajax events because the JSF change event doesn't trigger when you click on the calendar and the PrimeFaces dateSelect doesn't trigger when you type a date in.

I've tried the onSelectUpdate from the calendar and the render and update from both ajax events, setting them to @this, @form, the end date calendar's ID, both calendars' IDs, the calendar's outputPanel's ID and the common outputPanel's ID, and the damn calendars *just. Won't Update.*

I'm at my wits' end and my Google Fu doesn't find any solution that works either.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set an ajax event on the click of the start date calendar :

```
<p:calendar id="start_date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"  value="#{managedBean.startDate}"  size="20" >
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{managedBean.onSelectDate()}" update=":form:end_date" />
</p:calendar>   

<p:calendar id="end_date"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" mindate="#{managedBean.startDate}"  value="#{managedBean.endDate}"  size="20" />
```

When you select the startDate that triggers a method where you set endDate to null, and you update the endDate calendar, which is limited by `mindate="#{managedBean.startDate}"`

```
public void onSelectDate() {
    this.setEndDate(null);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, turns up that setting endDate to null doesn't help me refresh the p:calendar component. It just keeps showing the last value that has been visible.

Comment: Please follow the Java Naming Convention and write method names in first letter lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: f:ajax doesn't have an update attribute, in f:ajax you need to use the render attribute.

A p:remoteCommand with the ajax oncomplete Attribute should solve the problem:

```
<p:outputPanel id="fl83">
<p:remoteCommand name="updateCalendar" update="fl83" />
    <p:outputPanel id="fl83c3">
        <h:outputLabel value="Start date" for="fechaInicioMP" />
        <p:calendar locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="fechaInicioMP"
            maxdate="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaMaxFin}" value="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaInicio}"
            onSelectUpdate=":f183" >
            <p:ajax event="blur" />
            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaInicioTextChange}"
                oncomplete="updateCalendar()" />
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaInicioClickChange}"
                oncomplete="updateCalendar()" />
        </p:calendar>
    </p:outputPanel>
    <p:outputPanel id="fl83c4">
        <h:outputLabel value="End date" for="fechaFinMP" />
        <p:calendar locale="es" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" id="fechaFinMP"
            maxdate="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaMaxFin}" value="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaFin}"
            onSelectUpdate="f183" >
            <p:ajax event="blur" />
            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaFinTextChange}"
                oncomplete="updateCalendar()" />
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{filtroFechasBB.fechaFinClickChange}"
                oncomplete="updateCalendar()" />
        </p:calendar>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

If that doesn't solve the problem: do you've a form around it which modifies the ids? If you've a  without prependId="false" form1 is prepend to every id inside the form. So you'd need to access the panel with exampleForm:fl83.